# Why does “delete *this” ever compile?

Tags: c++, compilation, mfc

I am deriving a class from MFC `CDialogEx`:

```
class MyDialog : public CDialogEx
{
  public:
    virtual void PostNcDestroy();
    …
  …
};
```

I implemented `PostNcDestroy` [as such](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zba4hah.aspx):

```
void MyDialog::PostNcDestroy()
{
    CDialogEx::PostNcDestroy();
    delete *this; // oops, typo
}
```

I was surprised to see that this code compiles (using VC120, or Visual Studio 2013) , and generates no warning at all. Can anybody tell why this is the case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an implicit conversion; the class `CWnd` has an `operator HWND()` conversion function, and `HWND` is a pointer type.

Deleting that `HWND` is an error, but the compiler doesn't know that and can't warn you.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does “delete *this” ever compile?

It's possible to write a simple mcve that reproduces the behaviour that you're asking about:

```
struct foo {
    operator int*() {
        return nullptr;
    }

    void bar() {
       delete *this; 
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.bar();
}
```

This compiles because `foo` is implicitly convertible to a pointer type. Same could  be the case for your class.